# Angular 2 : Unhandled Promise rejection Template parse errors: Can't bind to '...' since it isn't a known property of '...'

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to create a separate module for all my directives. Because instead of importing all directives into app.module I am creating a separate module. here the code

**directive.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule, Injectable, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Tab } from './activetab.directive';
import { JqtDirective } from './jqte-editor.directive';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [    
    Tab,
    JqtDirective 
  ],
  imports: [ 
    FormsModule,
    BrowserModule
  ],
  schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
})
export class DirectivesModule { }
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, Injectable, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
......
......
import { DirectivesModule } from './shared/directives/directives.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    DirectivesModule
  ],
  providers: [ABCService],
  schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I am getting below error

```
  zone.js:388 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
    Can't bind to 'jqtevalue' since it isn't a known property of 'textarea'. ("                  <fieldset>                        
<textarea jqte-editor [ERROR ->][jqtevalue]="details" cols="20" id="noise" name="noise" class="nothing"></textarea>
```

Here **jqte-editor** is my selector name. Help me what is causing issue.